# Plpgsql: Is this possible way to create or drop the view in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql

Example:

--Creating view

```
execute 'create view "'||quote_ident(analysisname)||'"';
```

--Drop view

```
temp := 'drop view "'||quote_ident(analysisname)||'"';
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Getting error.                                                        ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: create view ""vAnalysis_View1""

Comment: Are you aware that your `create view` statement is incomplete? You need a `SELECT` statement for it. And please don't just throw code fragments at us, always post a complete reproducible example.

Comment: You need the `AS SELECT ...` part. And don't use double quotes there, you are already using `quote_ident`, you don't need to explictly add the quotes, the function does that if needed. The `DROP VIEW` is correct, just `EXECUTE temp;`.